# NestJS compilerOptions assets wrong path

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, nestjs-config

I don't really know hot to explain it but basically I have .hbs files which the mail resource needs. Normally they don't get copied into the `dist` folder when I run `npm start run:dev`. So I modified the `nest-cli.json` like this.

[image]

But now I have the problem that the patch which they are getting copied to are not correct.

This is how I have it in my root folder:

[image]

And this is where it gets copied to:

[image]

I´ve tried playing around with the assets path and searched for answers but I didn't find any other way of coping those files

Comment: The picture you have attached doesn't prove that `hbs` files are not under the templates directory. VSCode is doing a bit weird in showing directories that have only one sub-directory. You can double-check with your file manager to see.

Comment: Nope VSC shows it correctly there is no templates folder in src in the dist folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"compilerOptions": {    
"assets": [
  {
    "include": "/mail",
    "outDir": "dist/mail",
    "watchAssets": true
  },
],
"watchAssets": true
}
```

note that in your first image `templates` folder under `mail` folder is same as `mail/templates` in your second image. And this because you have only one folder under the parent folder

Comment: Thanks, `
I had to change `"outDir"` to `"dist/src/"` because the `mail` folder is located inside the `src` folder

Comment: no you don't need ! the src folder usually doesn't exist under dist. it's like considering dist as src

Comment: If want to copy folder outside of `src` to `dist` then `"assets": [
      {"include": "/../prisma/**/*", "outDir": "dist/prisma/"}
    ]` works